# Pytest not throwing errors where I expect them

Tags: python, pytest

When I run the following code, pytest gives me a failure. From my understanding based on [the docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.7.3/_modules/_pytest/runner.html) and [a question I asked on this plugin](https://github.com/rvprasad/pytest-finer-verdicts/issues/3#issuecomment-321927841) it should be returning an error.

I made a custom plugin just for this problem and the root of the issue seems to be that both setup and teardown pass, while call fails, hence why it's registering as a failure and not an error. I guess the better question is why doesn't setup fail?

I'm running on windows using pytest 3.1.2. Pip list shouldn't matter, though I will note that I don't have the above mentioned plugin installed and that my custom plugin only prints information.

I'm not sure if this is a bug or just my misunderstanding, so I decided to post both here and [on pytest's github](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/2677). Thank you for the help

```
import pytest
import unittest

class base(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        raise ValueError

class test(base):
    def test(self):
        print("Hello")

pytest.main()
```

Comment: It won't let me edit to add the link (need 10 reputation for more than 2 links), so here is my post on github:

https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/2677

Comment: I've edited that link into your question.

Comment: what is the name of your python file, if it does not start with `test`, just rename your file to `test_<original_filename>.py` and run. I am sure its going to work. I believe earlier you would have got something like `========================= no tests ran in 0.02 seconds =========================`, in case you have someother output, please share it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted a detailed answer in [pytest-dev/pytest#2677](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/2677#issuecomment-322597289).